# Recording and seeking to CSV file positions in Golang

Tags: file, csv, go, seek

I need to read a CSV file and record the locations of lines with certain values into an array, then later go back and retrieve those lines in no particular order and with good performance, so random access.

My program uses csv.NewReader(file), but I see no way to get or set the file offset that it uses. I tried file.Seek(0,io.SeekCurrent) to return the file position, but it doesn't change between calls to reader.Read(). I also tried fmt.Println("+v +v\n",reader,file) to see if anything stores the reader's file position, but I don't see it. I also don't know the best way to use the file position if I do find it.

Here's what I need to do:

```
file,_ = os.Open("stuff.csv")
reader = csv.NewReader(file)

//read file and record locations
for {
    line,_ = reader.Read()
    if wantToRememberLocation(line) {
         locations = append(locations, getLocation()) //need this function
    }
}

//then revisit certain lines
for {
    reader.GoToLine(locations[random])  //need this function
    line,_ = reader.Read()
    doStuff(line)
}
```

Is there even a way to do this with the csv library, or will I have to write my own using more primitive file io functions?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't some other way to do what you want? Can you just save the  records you're interested in? If you really need to save the file offsets of those lines, you might be able to make that work by creating your own reader to wrap the file object in. You would write your reader's `Read` method to never read past the end of a line in one call. If you have your reader save the offset of the current line and look at that after you do the `Read` on the CSV reader, I think that will give you the right offset. You'll have to play with it.

Comment: The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem: [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I'm building a tool to efficiently work with giant csv files and don't have the ram to save all the lines, so I need to save their locations. I'm considering building my own reader, but want to first see if I can do random access with the existing reader.

Comment: You can perhaps record all the newline position as the file is read (with a [TeeReader](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#TeeReader) for instance) and then correlate record numbers with newline positions. This only works if your files don't contain comments, empty lines, and quoted values with newlines.

Comment: Thanks Peter, that works. Using `io.TeeReader(file,buffer)` to make a copy of the line being read, `line,_ = buffer.ReadBytes('\n')` to get the line, then `len(line)` to get the size and add it to the running total to get the position works, but I hope this doesn't slow things down too much when reading 10,000,000 line CSVs. Still need to figure out a fast way to go back and parse individual lines as csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using TeeReader. This example just saves all the positions and goes back and rereads some of them.

```
//set up some vars and readers to record position and length of each line
type Record struct {
    Pos int64
    Len int 
}
records := make([]Record,1)
var buf bytes.Buffer
var pos int64
file,_ := Open("stuff.csv")
tr := io.TeeReader(file, &buf)
cr := csv.NewReader(tr)

//read first row and get things started
data,_ := cr.Read()
dostuff(data)
//length of current row determines position of next
lineBytes,_ := buf.ReadBytes('\n')
length := len(lineBytes)
pos += int64(length)
records[0].Len = length
records = append(records, Record{ Pos: pos })

for i:=1;;i++ {
    //read csv data
    data,err = c.Read()
    if err != nil {break}
    dostuff(data)
    //record length and position
    lineBytes,_ = buf.ReadBytes('\n')
    lenth = len(lineBytes)
    pos += int64(length)
    records[i].Len = length
    records = append(records, Record{ Pos: pos })
}

//prepare individual line reader
line := make([]byte,1000)
lineReader := bytes.NewReader(line)

//read random lines from file
for {
    i := someLineNumber()
    //use original file reader to fill byte slice with line
    file.ReadAt(line[:records[i].Len], records[i].Pos)
    //need new lineParser to start at beginning every time
    lineReader.Seek(0,0)
    lineParser := csv.NewReader(lineReader)
    data,_ = lineParser.Read()
    doStuff(data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

os.Open returns a File, which implements io.Seeker.

So you can do this to rewind the stream to the beginning:

```
_, err = file.Seek(0, io.SeekStart)
```

https://golang.org/src/os/file.go